# how to fill my collection list by using dataset in c#

Tags: c#, collections, arraylist, dataset

Firstly I created a collection which is  " Collection list;" and in a function RSS items includes Link Description Title which are string and Date which is Datetime variable, I tried to fill my collection list like this
Collection list;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                row = dt.Rows[i];
                list[i].Link = row[0].ToString();// 
                list[i].Description = row[1].ToString();
                list[i].Title = row[2].ToString();
             list[i].Date = DateTime.Parse(row[3].ToString()); 

            }
```

There are errors which are cannot modify the return value of because it is not a variable which is under list[i].

How can i solve this problem? thanks

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing the value into a DateTime:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    row = dt.Rows[i];
    list[i].Link = row[0].ToString();// 
    list[i].Description = row[1].ToString();
    list[i].Title = row[2].ToString();
    list[i].Date = DateTime.Parse(row[3].ToString());
}
```

I would be careful here though, since the value of row[3] may not be a valid date (is this some you can be sure of?)

In that case, you might want to have some defence:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    row = dt.Rows[i];
    list[i].Link = row[0].ToString();// 
    list[i].Description = row[1].ToString();
    list[i].Title = row[2].ToString();
    list[i].Date = ToDateTime(row[3].ToString());
}

public static DateTime? ToDateTime(string value)
{
    DateTime result;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Make sure `list.Date` is declared as `DateTime?`. Using this avoids having exceptions raised if row[3] is not a valid date if you called `DateTime.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list[i].Date =Convert.ToDateTime(row[3]);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Not considering DBNull.Value, you should try to convert row[3] in a DateTime

```
string toConvert = row[3].ToString(); 
DateTime result;
if(DateTime.TryParse(toConvert, out result) == true)
    list[i].Date = result;
```